# Stub Httparty call: Wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, httparty, webmock

I created a simple ruby file (not Rails) and I am trying to test (using `Rspec`) a method where I am calling an API. In the test I am trying to mock the call via `WebMock` but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Requests::FilesManager#display fetches the files from the API
     Failure/Error: Requests::FilesManager.new.display
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

The files are:

```
#run.rb
module Requests
  require "httparty"
  require 'json'

  class FilesManager
      include HTTParty

      def initialize

      end

      def display
        response = HTTParty.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries', format: :json)
        parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
        puts "The secret message was: #{parsed_response["message"]}"
      end
  end
end
```

and the spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../run'

RSpec.describe Requests::FilesManager do
  describe "#display" do
    it 'fetches the files from the API' do
      stub_request(:get, "https://api.publicapis.org/entries").
        to_return(status: 200, body: "", headers: {})

      Requests::FilesManager.new.display
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:
So the error seems to come from the line:

```
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

If I comment it out it disappears. The problem then is that the output of the call is not a `json` (even with the `format: :json` when calling the HTTParty). I tried other solutions but nothing seems to work in making the response json. It is just a string.

Comment: The problem is not with the mock but in this line: `Requests::MyCLI.new.display_files`. What does `Requests::MyCLI` look like and how are its `initialize` and `display_files` methods defined?

Comment: Thank for the reply. Apologies, I updated the error @spickermann. Any ideas why it is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

1. It seems there was an error because the `json` gem version that `HTTParty` uses is too old.
2. Moved on to `RestClient` gem for the RESTful API calls. It had another conflict in the `mime` gem versioning.
3. Finally moved to `Faraday` and that solved my problems:

```
JSON.parse(response.body, :quirks_mode => true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`response = HTTParty.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries', format: :json)`

to

`response = HTTParty.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')`.

I think you don't need the `format: :json` more so when you explicitly format the response to JSON anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but the error keeps appearing..

Comment: Found where the error was coming from but another hurdle appears, I updated the questions in hopes someone might help

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a json object in the `body` parameter of the stubbed response:

E.g: For an empty response:

```
  stub_request(:get, "https://api.publicapis.org/entries").
    to_return(status: 200, body: "".to_json, headers: {})
```

OR For a valid response: (Note: You may have to require json to convert a hash to json)

```
require 'json'
...

  stub_request(:get, "https://api.publicapis.org/entries").
    to_return(status: 200, body:  { entries: { '0': { message: "Hello World" } } }.to_json, headers: {})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Tried it out but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Also created a `body` exactly the same to what it should result but it still fails

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr Had the same issue and ended up having to upgrade webmock.

Long form:

Webmock inserts middleware into your calls, so when HTTParty makes the calls they end up going through the Webmock interfaces first.

You can verify this by trying the call standalone (withouth all the rspec config):

```
bundle console
irb> require "httparty"
=> true
irb> httparty.get("https://google.com")
```

If that standalone call succeeds, the issue is somewhere within Webmock itself.

For me, somewhere along the line of calls through Webmock was an outdated interface that was incompatible and throwing the Wrong Number of Arguments error. And this was also crashing my debugger (RubyMine).

Upgrading Webmock solved this issue (because they had fixed it in newer versions).

Comment: If this is not the case, let me know and I will remove the answer to not confuse people.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, my bad I already found out the answer a while ago but didn't mark it as solved. I see no issue in leaving your answer here though! It will be valuable for other people for sure